# Change '\\A', to '\A'

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Suppose such a list,

```
l = ['\\number', '\\A', '\\b', '\\B', '\\d', '\\D', '\\s', '\\S', '\\w', '\\W', '\\Z']
```

I'd like to get a result:

```
l = ['\number', '\A', '\b', '\B', '\d', '\D', '\s', '\S', '\w', '\W', '\Z']
```

Handle it with regex

```
In [35]: [re.sub(r'\\(?=\\w+)', '',i) for i in l]
Out[35]:
['\\',
 '\\number',
 '\\A',
 '\\b',
 '\\B',
 '\\d',
 '\\D',
 '\\s',
 '\\S',
 '\\w',
 '\\W',
 '\\Z']
```

It failed to work as I expected.

How to accomplish such a task using regex?

Comment: [Your solution is working well](https://ideone.com/ADUhzx).

Comment: No, the demo print them not encapsulate them in a list @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search By this:

```
\\\\(?!\\)
```

and

replace by this:

```
\\
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JMCoPQ/4)